# Kernel block device

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, block-device

I'm currently trying to implement a (not that ?) simple kernel block device driver.

I inspired mainly from the book [Linux Device Drivers, 3rd Edition](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596005903/) which is not totally up-to-date anymore as it was published in 2005.

Anyway the logic is still there and I learnt a lot from it. However examples are not really effective as many things have changed since 2005.

I found a [github repository](https://github.com/martinezjavier/ldd3) where examples should be updated to work on recent kernels but I think there is still some things to update as I can't adapt examples to make it work on **kernel 4.9.0**

***Here is how my module is made:***

At initialization :

- Register the module as block device with `register_blkdev`
- Allocate the device data buffer
- Initialize spinlock
- Initialize request queue
- Configure request queue
- Allocate `gendisk` structure
- Fill `gendisk` structure
- Create the disk with `add_disk`

Then I implemented a function to handle request events from request queue and treat read and write events on the block device.

Here is the function : (It's highly inspired from LLD-3rd with some modifications to match current kernel functions)

```
static void block_mod_request(struct request_queue *queue)
{
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "Entering request function\n");
    struct request *request;

    while(NULL != (request = blk_fetch_request(queue)))
    {
        blk_mod_t *self = request->rq_disk->private_data;
        // Check if request is a filesystem request (i.e. moves block of data)
        if(REQ_TYPE_FS != request->cmd_type)
        {
            // Close request with unsuccessful status
            printk(KERN_WARNING "Skip non-fs request\n");
            __blk_end_request_cur(request, -EIO);
            continue;
        }
        // Treat request
        block_mod_transfer(self, blk_rq_pos(request), blk_rq_cur_sectors(request), request->buffer, rq_data_dir(request));
        // Close request with successful status
        __blk_end_request_cur(request, 0);
    }
    return;
}
```

However at compiling I got the following error:

```
block_mod.c:82:91: error: ‘struct request’ has no member named ‘buffer’
         block_mod_transfer(self, blk_rq_pos(request), blk_rq_cur_sectors(request), request->buffer, rq_data_dir(request));
```

After checking file `blkdev.h` into kernel v4.9.0 headers, it seems that the field `buffer` no longer exists into `struct request`.
However I'm not able to find any information on how things have evolved and how to modify the code to make it work.

If I understand well, the `buffer` field is supposed to be a pointer to a virtual kernel address. I suppose that once this buffer filled/read the kernel handles the transfer of data to/from userspace.

I'm kinda lost because I can't find where I should find the kernel virtual address if it's not given by the request anymore.

***How am I supposed to know where to transfert data?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message from the commit containing the culprit change, authored by Ming Lei:

> block: remove struct request buffer member
>
> This was used in the olden days, back when onions were proper
>      yellow. Basically it mapped to the current buffer to be
>      transferred. With highmem being added more than a decade ago,
>      most drivers map pages out of a bio, and `rq->buffer` isn't
>      pointing at anything valid.
>
> Convert old style drivers to just use `bio_data()`.

There are some good resources for reading about BIO, such as [this post](https://lwn.net/Articles/26404/) on lwn. A relevant snippet:

> `char *bio_data(struct bio *bio)`
>
> Returns the kernel virtual address for the data buffer.

So it looks like you will have more success using `bio_data(rq->bio)` in place of `rq->buffer`.

***Edit by author:***
Also found [this link](https://lwn.net/Articles/736534/) which is in two parts and presents in first part the bio layer and in second part the request layer.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! That's exactly what I was looking for. I'll go further into bio documentation because it seems more complete than just using buffers. However the link you gave me seems to be outdated too (no `bi_sector` field into `struct bio` for example but reachable with `bio->bi_iter.bi_sector`). Maybe you know where I can find up-to-date documentation ?